# List slice assignment with resize using negative indices

Tags: python, list, slice, variable-assignment

If I do this:

```
p=list(range(10))
p[2:6:1]=['a','b']
```

I get `p=[0, 1, 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 8, 9]` which means Python is replacing the the elements indexed 2-5 with the new list `['a','b']`.

Now when, I do

```
p=list(range(10))
p[-2:-6:-1]=['a','b']
```

Python says `ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 2 to extended slice of size 4`

Why does it resize the list in the first case but not the second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior for *extended* slices. As you have discovered, it requires the same number of elements to be assigned to the slice. Here's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) that refers to the issue.

It becomes more obvious why if instead you sliced `p[1:5:2]`. It's not a nice contiguous block that you can easily resize.

`p[2:6:1]` works because it's essentially a regular slice, ie `p[2:6]`.

Comment: So any slice with a stride not equal to 1 is an extended slice?

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact inner working of python list slicing, but it probably has something to do with the fact that `p[-2:-6:-1]` works backwards through the list instead of forwards.

If you want a quick fix, use:
`p[-6:-2:1] = ['a', 'b']`

That way, you'll work from 'left to right' again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html), an assignment to a regular slice (you first one) can be used to change the length of the sequence, while  extended slices aren't this flexible.

**When assigning to an extended slice, the list on the right hand side of the statement must contain the same number of items as the slice it is replacing.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because ['a', 'b'] propagated forward, but your indexing of '-1' forces it to propagate backwards.

You could do the same using:

```
p[-6:-2:1] = ['a', 'b']
```

But if you want increase the length from 10 to 12, you could try this:

```
p[-2:-6:1]=['a','b']
```

or:

```
p[-2:-6]=['a','b']
```

This both will give:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'a', 'b', 8, 9]
```